# if-clause seems not to be executed under certain arbitrary conditions

Tags: perl, debugging, if-statement, input

I am trying to divide a triangular matrix into parts, which hold approximately the same amount of elements.

I wrote the following code, which works nicely for most combinations of inputs, and segments my matrix into the given number of parts from 0 to `$length`.

However, there are input combinations like `$length = 2003` and `$number_of_segments = 50`, where the last segment is missing in the output.
I tested the values of `$threshold` and `$total`, but they seem to be correct even in those odd cases.

Do you have any ideas, where the bug is?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;         #should always be used
use warnings;       #that one too
use autodie;        #just in case I forgot to check anything

my $length = shift or die "ERROR: Not enough arguments!\n";         #number of rows in the matrix
my $number_of_segments = shift or die "ERROR: Not enough arguments!\n";     #number of segments we want to get

my @segments = &divide;         #array of segment-limits
print "$_\n" foreach @segments;

sub divide {
    my @segments = (0);         #the first segment starts at 0
    my $number_of_pairs = ($length*($length+1))/2;          #number of elements in matrix
    my $total = 0;          #counter for the elements we already visited
    my $segment_counter = 1;        #we are in the first segment

    for (my $i=0; $i<$length; $i++){        #going over the rows of the matrix
        $total += $length-$i;           #counting the elements in each row
        my $threshold = ($number_of_pairs/$number_of_segments)*$segment_counter;        #threshold for the next segment
        if ($total >= $threshold){          #if our current segment is large enough
            push @segments, $i+1;              #save the limit
            $segment_counter++;            #and open the next segment
        }
    }

    return @segments;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't call Perl subroutines with an ampersand `&`. That is a Perl 4 style that is well over 20 years out of date. Just `divide()` is right, or even `divide` if you pre-declare the subroutine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't generally compare floating-point numbers for equality because of their limited accuracy. The final value of `$threshold` comes out fractionally high (2007006.0000000002 on my 32-bit Perl) so you have to allow for a margin of error.

If you change the test to

```
if ( $total + 1E-8 >= $threshold ) { ... }
```

then you will get the results you expect. You may have to adjust the delta value to get the correct results.

Note that this is a very slow and inaccurate way of doing things. You should really keep all the arithmetic to *integers* instead of floating point values, but I don't have time at present to refactor your code

Comment: Would it be more elegant to use int($total) or does that pose the possibility of other errors?

Comment: @glykokalyx: Yeah, I guess since you're doing `>=` the only problem might be that the number is too high, so I think that should work. But it would be `if ( $total >= int($threshold) ) { ... }` as the `$total` values are already integers

Comment: @glykokalyx: Actually, thinking again, if your threshold was *under* the correct value - say 2007005.99999998 - then taking `int` of that would give you 2007005, whcih will give the wrong result. Stick to my original soluition